# SoundCloud - Any workaround for the offset/limit limits?

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to collect information from SoundCloud which involves collecting lists beyond the limit = 200 and offset = 8000 constraints. For example, I would like to collect all the followers of a user, and some users have hundreds of thousands of followers... Is there some way to get around the limit of 8000?